# PhantomJS command prompt (cmd) runs forever without HAR data

Tags: phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS 2.0.0 to capture netsniff data from a website.

1. I've tested with a few example sites like google and stackoverflow.com - it spits out HAR JSON data almost instantaneously
2. I'm having issue with one of our site and the command prompt just stays on forever. I've waited for, like 15 minutes. (Page size is ~2.5 MB)

Command used: **phantomjs C:\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\examples\netsniff.js http://www.testwebsitexyz.com > c:\out.txt**

Any help is most appreciated.

Regards,
SatP

Comment: Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events inside of netsniff ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Excellent! I registered to all the events and I got a "Success" message. What's more - now I used the original netsniff and I got the HAR file. Thank you.